# dll на Visual C++ для подключения к проекту на C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

На VC++ написал dll'ку со следующим содержимым:

```
using namespace::std;
define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
public class TestDll
{

public:
    MATHFUNCSDLL_API bool  EmptyMethod();
    static MATHFUNCSDLL_API bool EmptyMethod1();
};


bool TestDll::EmptyMethod()
{
    return false;
}

 bool TestDll::EmptyMethod1()
{
    return false;
}
```

В проекте на C# соответственно добавляю ссылку на данную dll и пытаюсь вызвать методы определённые в dll. Но дело в том, что при подключении dll экземпляр класса TestDll создать можно, но у него нет методов которые определены в dll. Только базовые, наследуемые от object.

Что я делаю не так? Как на Visual C++ написать dll'ку методы которой можно будет вызывать на C# без использования [Dllimport]

Comment: В Visual C++ используете C++/CLI или нативный?

Comment: Чем не устраивает [DllImport]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using namespace::std;

public ref class TestDll
{

public:
     bool  EmptyMethod();
    static  bool EmptyMethod1();
};


bool TestDll::EmptyMethod()
{
    return false;
}

 bool TestDll::EmptyMethod1()
{
    return false;
}
```

Приведённый выше код корректно грузится в C# проекты при условии, что С++ dll'ка скомпилирована с параметром "Поддержка CLR"